# Timeout NCURSES and buffers

Tags: ncurses

I'm trying to add some details to a terminal application that I'm creating with ncurses.

The application is something like a quiz with timeout... if the user wastes too much time, timeout happens and cleans the screen.

Now the problem: how can I show the text that the user had inserted before timeout and edit/reedit if he wants?

Example:

Q:Do you feel happy? (correct answer Yes, I feel happy)

A:Yes, I fe (TIMEOUT, clean the screen, question is printed again but no "Yes, I fe" is printed).

I don't know if there is any possibility to add this to the stdin buffer or line buffer...

Ideas...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like that:

- disable blocking keyboard reads by calling `nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);`
- in a loop, check if a key was pressed using `getch()` and checking if it returns a value>0

  - if yes, process the key as usual
  - else sleep a few microseconds(no busy waiting!) using `usleep()` and check for timeout; if the timeout happened, process it